# I need help showing that $\delta(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{xy}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I need help showing that $\delta(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{xy}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{N}$. I have all of the trivial properties, I just need to show the triangle inequality holds. That is, $\delta(x,y)\leq \delta(x,z)+\delta(z,y)$.

Comment: Write $\delta$ as $\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|$.

Comment: Wow that made it so much easier! Thanks @anomaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show : $\frac{|x-z|}{xz} \leq \frac{|x-y|}{xy} + \frac{|y-z|}{yz} = \frac{z|x-y| + x|y-z|}{xyz} = \frac{|xz-yz| + |xy-xz|}{xyz}$. We observe:

$$
|xy-yz| \leq |xy-xz| + |xz-yz|
$$
for any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$, by the triangle inequality. But:
$$
|xy-yz| \leq |xy-xz| + |xz-yz| \implies y|x-z| \leq x|y-z| + z|x-y|
\\ \implies \frac{|x-z|}{xz} \leq \frac{|y-z|}{yz} + \frac{|x-y|}{xy} \implies d(x,y) \leq d(y,z) + d(x,y) = d(x,y) + d(y,z)
$$
which is the triangle inequality for the metric. Note that the key step is that we can multiply by $\frac{1}{xyz}$ on both sides of the inequality without flipping sign, because $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N} \implies \frac{1}{xyz} > 0$